# Why are no lines drawn on my (custom View) canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I'm trying to draw a lines from points in a `float[]`. I know that the points get to the `drawLines()` function because I log them here:

> Draw Points:  : 154.18182 : 784.8889 : 215.27272 : 677.3333 :
>   215.27272 : 677.3333 : 337.45453 : 462.22217 : 337.45453 : 462.22217 : 276.36365 : 569.7778 : 276.36365 : 569.7778 : 398.54544 : 354.66663 : 398.54544 : 354.66663 : 154.18182 : 784.8889 : 154.18182 : 784.8889 : 337.45453 : 462.22217 : 337.45453 : 462.22217 : 520.7273 : 139.55554 : 520.7273 : 139.55554 : 581.8182 : 32.0 : 581.8182 : 32.0 : 398.54544 : 354.66663 : 398.54544 : 354.66663 : 154.18182 : 784.8889

**Note: pay no attention to the duplication of points - the end point of the first line is the start point of the second line. The drawLines function requires four consecutive points, hence the duplication of points.*

My `width` and `height` are valid `integers`: `Width = 672 Height = 968`

**My `onDraw` function:**

Note that I've already tried a few things which are now commented out. My background is grey, so the `Color.RED` line should be visible, when it's ever drawn.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    //setWillNotDraw(true);

    Log.d(TAG, "DRAW DAMNIT!!!");
    Log.d(TAG, "Width = " + (int) width + " Height = " + (int)height);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    //paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    //paint.setShadowLayer(4, 2, 2, 0x81000000);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    String drawPointsGo = "";
    float[] drawPoints = new float[points.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<points.size(); i++){
        Float f = points.get(i);
        drawPoints[i] = (float) (f != null ? f : 0.0);
        drawPointsGo = drawPointsGo + " : " + drawPoints[i];
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Draw Points: " + drawPointsGo);

    canvas.drawLines(drawPoints, paint);
}
```

**My XML:**

```
<za.co.widge.test.linegraph.LineGraphView 
    android:id="@+id/linechart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#444"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

**Result:**
The grey block appears on the phone's screen, but no red line is drawn.

**Why is nothing drawn on my (custom `View`) `canvas`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this lines:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
```

You are overwriting canvas instance passed to your onDraw method with offscreen (bitmap backed) one, so nothing is plot on screen.